# Built an app with wxPython to send requests to REST API using Windows auth, but the app gets stuck at requests.post when compiled

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, wxpython, pyinstaller

I tried to build an app (see a simplified version below) using wxPython that sends requests to a REST API endpoint using the `requests` package and the `requests_negotiate_sspi` package for Windows authentication. When I run the script in the command line without compiling it with `pyinstaller` - i.e., `python main_test.py` - the app runs fine: the `wx.Dialog` widget after `requests.post` pops up. However, if I compile the script and execute the executable instead, the app gets stuck at `requests.post`, and as a result, the second `wx.Dialog` doesn't pop up. I wonder if anyone knows why this might be the case. Thanks!

```
import wx 
import sys
import subprocess
import pyodbc
import requests
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth


class main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(main, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(50, 100))
        
                
        self.Button = wx.Button(self, label="Post", size=(50, 100))
        self.Button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPost)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()
        
    def OnPost(self, evt): 
        dlg = wx.Dialog(self, title= "Before POST")
        dlg.Show()
        r = requests.post('path/to/endpoint', 
                         auth=HttpNegotiateAuth(), 
                         params=DICTIONARY_OF_PARAMETERS})
        
        dlg = wx.Dialog(self, title= "Post POST")
        dlg.Show()
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame = main(None, title = "Main Test")
    MainFrame.Show()
    MainFrame.Centre()    
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: @Alexander I wonder if it has to do with some kind of internal network issue -- the Rest API is hosted on an intra-network server. It definitely doesn't work for me. In fact, if I remove the argument `auth=HttpNegotiateAuth()`, which would not let me access the endpoint (if I were to send the request in the Python interpreter without the argument, I'd get the `Not Authorized` error), I'd move pass that request line.

Comment: It works for me with or without the `auth=HttpNegotiateAuth()` parameter.  Although I think that is the reason why it is failing for you.  I don't know if you compiled it with `-w` mode,  If you did, then try not doing that.  That way if there are errors it will show you in the terminal